# Can we order the items (comments, answers) in activity tab as well?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, sorting

While it's possible to order some activities in their own 'widgets' (answers and questions may be ordered by votes/activity/freshness), I wonder is it appropriate to be able to sort them in 'activity tab' too. Also, it'd be really fun to have a chance of ordering comments by votes there. )

Comment: Currently the best you can do is filter by type of activity. Sub-filters or sorting could be useful. Perhaps grouping suggested edits by approval/rejection, sorting comments by votes, revisions by answer/question/tag wiki. That might be about it (no need to add anything to the posts page, since that is handled already by questions and answers)

Comment: ...Would I be correct in concluding that, as of the changes to the profile page, this has effectively been implemented? (At least for questions and answers – comments don't have their own section there.)